# equally spaced divs. Multiple rows

Tags: css

I have a list of video thumbnails displayed on page. Of course they don't fit in one line, so multiple lines are used and I would like them to be spaced equally (in other case layout look  broken). My current markup is

```
.thumbs {
 width: 76%;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 1em;
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: #DEE;
}

.thumb {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left;
}
```

markup is:

```
            <div class="thumbs">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
                    <div class="title">Test</div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
                    <div class="title">Test</div>
                </div>
                <!-- and so forth... -->
            </div>
```

Same in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cPm9f/

Everything is ok except the last row: I expect it to be spaced as previous rows, but space differs :( I can't use a table or just stuff a bunch of invisible stub elements because this is a foundation for responsive design so amount of columns displayed will be dependent
on width of device screen.

Any ideas how to make the last row space equally to previous ones?

**UPD:** There's opinion by cimmanon that what I want should be implemented differently. If so then how?

Comment: You'll have to code it differently.  The problem is the way justify works.  See what happens when you replace the images with a paragraph of text?  http://jsfiddle.net/cPm9f/2/  The last line never extends all the way to the right.

Comment: But how then should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the interpretation of `text-align: justify`. The last line is commonly not justified, because if the last line is rather short, the letters would need to have an absurd spacing.

Workaround:

```
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```

But to my knowledge `text-align-last` is only supported by IE **[EDIT: and Mozilla with `-moz-text-align-last`]**, so let us just fake another line of justifiable text for the others:

```
.thumbs:after { display: inline-block; width: 100%; content: ""; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TWgDh/

Answer (score 1):

```
.thumb:last-child {
    float:right;
}
​
```

? :)

http://jsfiddle.net/cPm9f/1/

Comment: ermm no. I want them to be left aligned. In other case that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you can use that but just be aware that the [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3alast-child) CSS pseudo-class isn't supported in any IE browsers below IE9. I don't know what you plan on supporting but it's worth knowing. The [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo-class, however, has *some* support in earlier versions of IE.

Comment: I've told in comment above that this solution doesn't fit.